# Porque no cargan las imagenes o documentos en un subdirectorio de ASSETS

Tags: angular7

Las imagenes y los documentos en subdirectorios de assets no cargan y van a la pagina de no encontrado; dan error 404

**angular.json**

```
...
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/servicios",
              "src/assets/reglamentos",
              "src/assets/images"
            ]
          }
```

...

y la imagen es

```html
<img src="./assets/servicios/{{servicio.imagen1}}" alt="{{servicio.nombre}}"/>
```

p  ej:

```html
<img src="./assets/servicios/perro.jpg" alt="Perro"/>
```

¿Me  pueden ayudar?

Comment: No he puesto al angular.json completo porque no me ha dejado

Comment: Tengo el proyecto dividido en dos, no se donde ejecuta localhost:4200 y el apache tomcat que es donde esta subiendo las imagenes, tengo que integrar el proyecto angular y el proyecto java que se ejecuta en el tomcat

Comment: Supongo que hare despliegue pero no queria utilizar maven